# Как подключить БД к проекту Android с поиском

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Есть готовая БД со словами и их переводами. Как интегрировать ее в проект?

Примерно хотя бы, и какой алгоритм поиска нужен.

Comment: Android Studio - средство разработки, которых много и в любой из них подключение БД к проекту будет выполнено одинаково, поэтому упоминания данной IDE здесь совершенно лишние, хоть она вам и нравится

Comment: А что вы пробовали сделать? Что у вас есть уже в проекте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. При установке приложения инициализируете новую(пустую) БД в папке установки приложения. После при первом старте переливаете данные из вашей БД(к примеру она у вас будет на карте памяти) в БД которую создали
2. При старте приложения проверяете наличие БД в папке установки, в случае её отсутсвия предлагаете выбрать БД на карте памяти(к примеру) и копируете её кодом в папку установки
3. Используете БД на карте памяти

[Пример копирования БД из папки assets](http://icetea09.com/blog/2014/01/22/android-use-existing-sqlite-database-in-android-app/)

[Пример копирования БД из карты памяти в папку приложения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850278/how-to-use-sqlite-database-from-sd-card)

[Пример использования БД на карте памяти](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373863/how-to-store-sqlite-database-directly-on-sdcard)

**Примечание:** во всех случаях обратите внимание на установку прав в манифесте на [чтение/запись карты памяти](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html?hl=ru)